# NASM x86_64 having trouble writing command line arguments, returning -14 in rax

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, nasm

I am using elf64 compilation and trying to take a parameter and write it out to the console.

I am calling the function as ./test wooop

After stepping through with gdb there seems to be no problem, everything is set up ok:

rax: 0x4
rbx: 0x1
rcx: pointing to string, x/6cb $rcx gives 'w' 'o' 'o' 'o' 'p' 0x0
rdx: 0x5  <---correctly determining length

after the int 80h rax contains -14 and nothing is printed to the console.
If I define a string in .data, it just works. gdb shows the value of $rcx in the same way.

Any ideas? here is my full source

```
    %define LF      0Ah
    %define stdout      1
    %define sys_exit    1
    %define sys_write   4


    global _start

    section .data

    usagemsg: db "test {string}",LF,0

    testmsg: db "wooop",0

    section .text

    _start:

    pop rcx     ;this is argc
    cmp rcx, 2      ;one argument
    jne usage
    pop rcx
    pop rcx               ; argument now in rcx
    test    rcx,rcx
    jz usage

    ;mov rcx, testmsg    ;<-----uncomment this to print ok!

    call print
    jmp exit


    usage:
    mov rcx, usagemsg
    call print
    jmp exit


    calclen:

    push rdi
    mov rdi, rcx
    push rcx
    xor rcx,rcx
    not rcx
    xor al,al
    cld
    repne scasb
    not rcx  
    lea rdx, [rcx-1]
    pop rcx
    pop rdi
    ret

    print:

    push rax
    push rbx
    push rdx

    call calclen

    mov rax, sys_write
    mov rbx, stdout
    int 80h
    pop rdx
    pop rbx
    pop rax
    ret

    exit:
    mov rax, sys_exit
    mov rbx, 0
    int 80h
```

Thanks

EDIT: After changing how I make my syscalls as below it works fine. Thanks all for your help!

sys_write is now 1
sys_exit is now 60
stdout now goes in rdi, not rbx
the string to write is now set in rsi, not rcx
int 80h is replaced by syscall

Comment: Related: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) covers the general case.  -EFAULT on a pointer to stack memory is a common symptom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm still running 32-bit hardware, so this is a wild asmed guess! As you probably know, 64-bit system call numbers are completely different, and "syscall" is used instead of int 80h. However int 80h and 32-bit system call numbers can still be used, with 64-bit registers truncated to 32-bit. Your tests indicate that this works with addresses in .data, but with a "stack address", it returns -14 (-EFAULT - bad address). The only thing I can think of is that truncating rcx to ecx results in a "bad address" if it's on the stack. I don't know where the stack is in 64-bit code. Does this make sense?

I'd try it with "proper" 64-bit system call numbers and registers and "syscall", and see if that helps.

Best,
Frank

Comment: +1. Very good answer! I wouldn't have even thought of something so obvious.

Comment: +1. Thanks, that was the problem. after changing my syscall numbers and which registers I use it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you're using ELF64 as the target of the compilation. This is, unfortunately, your first mistake. Using the "old" system call interface on Linux, e.g. `int 80h` is possible only when running 32-bit tasks. Obviously, you could simply assemble your source as ELF32, but then you're going to lose all the advantages if running tasks in 64-bit mode, namely the extra registers and 64-bit operations.

In order to make system calls in 64-bit tasks, the "new" system call interface must be used. The system call itself is done with the `syscall` instruction. The kernel destroys registers `rcx` and `r11`. The number of the system is specified in the register `rax`, while the arguments of the call are passed in `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `r10`, `r8` and `r9`. Keep in mind that the numbers of the syscalls are different than the ones in 32-bit mode. You can find them in `unistd_64.h`, which is usually in `/usr/include/asm` or wherever your distribution stores it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I hadn't considered the syscall itself was the issue, if only it hadn't worked fine with the defined string I'd have been more suspicious.

Comment: According to the Intel manuals about the `syscall` instruction, not the kernel destroys `rcx` and `r11`, but the CPU does, in that it saves the instruction pointer to the former and the flags to the latter. `sysret` restores them afterwards to continue normal program flow.